# how to use multiple domains and mask a django project

Tags: python, django, apache, dns

I have a Django website that's configured on a particular domain `example.com`. Now I'm planning to use the same website for different countries where I have to use their language. For example China, I'm planning to create a sub domain `chinese.example.com` which will point to exactly the same `example.com` project but the language will be switched to chinese. Also I would like to mask this `chinese.example.com` sub domain with another domain `chinaexample.com`. Please advise how to accomplish this using Apache & Django.

Comment: add your domain to 'django.contrib.sites' model

Comment: do you have any idea about domain masking and apache /wsgi configuration?

Answer (score 0):

First step - make sure that all of your domains are added into 'ALLOWED_HOSTS' in django config.

Next - if you will have some content that will be available only for particular domain, it will be handy to use sites framework built into django. But if you want to have one language on multiple domains and want some content to be available for language, not for domain, better solution might be to create own method for assigning content to domain (or language).

Third step - write middleware that will check your domain and activate language assigned to it. Example middleware can look like this:

```
class DomainLanguageMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):

        try:
            host = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
            host_port = host.split(':')
            if len(host_port) == 2:
                host = host_port[0]

            if host in settings.LANG_MAP:
                request.LANG = settings.LANG_MAP[host]
                translation.activate(request.LANG)
                request.LANGUAGE_CODE = request.LANG
        except KeyError:
            pass
```

This code is using `LANG_MAP` setting, that should be an dictionary containing domain as key and language assigned to that domain as value.

Using that solution, all domains or subdomains can point to one django instance, with one settings.py file.